# mongoose: how to sort with aggregate search

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this aggregate search function

```
filter = { 'games.game_info.game_time': -1 };
.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {}
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        games: 1,
                        game_number: {
                            $size: '$games'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $facet: {
                        paginatedResult: [ { $sort: filter } ]
                    }
                }
            ])
```

games has this array.

```
  games:  [
      {
        game_id: '1',
        game_type: 'GTA5',
        game_info: {
          game_time: '2021-01-17 02:30:00.000Z',
          sports_code: '2'
        },
      },
      {
        game_id: '2',
        game_type: 'GTA5',
        game_info: {
          game_time: '2021-01-17 08:45:00.000Z',
          sports_code: '2'
        },
      }
    ]
```

I am trying to `sort` the list by the time. However, I am stuck on this. Tried various methods. How can I make `filter` works with +1 or -1 in order to sort the list by closest or latest time?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the data before it is responded, or are you trying to sort the entire db collection?

Comment: I am trying to sort the document that is returned from `$project` pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it like this.You can also get total number of records using $count.

```
Games.aggregate([
        {
            $facet: {
                data: [
                    { $match: { game_type: 'GTA5' } },
                    { $sort: { 'game_info.game_time': -1 } }
                ],
                total_count: [
                     { $count: 'count' }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Hope it helped... :)